# Is there a way to create a WHERE variable in an SQL SELECT request to avoid repetitions?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, sql-like

I'm looking for a way to put `CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))` into a single variable so that it doesn't need to be typed out hundreds of times for an SQL search with hundreds of `OR LIKE` parts.

```
SELECT
  WT.Sku AS Sku
  , WS.View AS View
  , WT.TitleA AS TitleA
  , WT.Index AS Index
  , WT.CondB AS CondB
  , WT.TitleF AS TitleF
  , WT.PublisherA AS PublisherA
  , WT.SeriesA AS SeriesA

FROM
  wt_table_one AS WT
  INNER JOIN public.ws_table_one AS WS ON WT.Index = WS.Index
WHERE
  WS.View = 17
  AND (
  CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%PANTHER%'
  OR CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%WISHING%'
  OR (CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%MIGHTY%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%THOR%')
  OR (CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%ANIMAL%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%CROSSING%')
  OR (CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%BRIAN%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%BLESSED%')
  OR (CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%ONE%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%OF%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%A%' AND CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))  LIKE '%KIND%')
  )
LIMIT 10000
```

(There are about another hundred or so `LIKE` conditions but I've cut it down here)

I'm new to SQL so bear with me, but I have tried the following.

```
SELECT
  @concvar :=CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))
  ,WT.Sku AS Sku
...
```

```
SET @concvar =CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))
SELECT
  WT.Sku AS Sku
...
```

from https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch01s15.html

Everything is still working fine without as it is, but I'd rather just have one place to update this rather than several hundred.

-Edit-
My goal would be something like this.

```
CONCATVAR = CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA))

SELECT
  WT.Sku AS Sku
  , WS.View AS View
  , WT.TitleA AS TitleA
  , WT.Index AS Index
  , WT.CondB AS CondB
  , WT.TitleF AS TitleF
  , WT.PublisherA AS PublisherA
  , WT.SeriesA AS SeriesA

FROM
  wt_table_one AS WT
  INNER JOIN public.ws_table_one AS WS ON WT.Index = WS.Index
WHERE
  WS.View = 17
  AND (
  CONCATVAR  LIKE '%PANTHER%'
  OR CONCATVAR  LIKE '%WISHING%'
  OR (CONCATVAR  LIKE '%MIGHTY%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%THOR%')
  OR (CONCATVAR  LIKE '%ANIMAL%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%CROSSING%')
  OR (CONCATVAR  LIKE '%BRIAN%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%BLESSED%')
  OR (CONCATVAR  LIKE '%ONE%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%OF%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%A%' AND CONCATVAR  LIKE '%KIND%')
  )
LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: On a side note: `CONCAT_WS('', ...)` glues the strings directly togther. `WT.TitleA = 'TIME SPAN'` plus `WT.CondB = 'THERE MUST BE TWO MONTHS LEFT'` becomes `'TIME SPANTHERE MUST BE TWO MONTHS LEFT'` which matches `'%PANTHER%'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    WT.Sku AS Sku
    , WS.View AS View
    , WT.TitleA AS TitleA
    , WT.Index AS Index
    , WT.CondB AS CondB
    , WT.TitleF AS TitleF
    , WT.PublisherA AS PublisherA
    , WT.SeriesA AS SeriesA
FROM (
    SELECT
        WT.*,
        CONCAT_WS('',upper(WT.TitleA),upper(WT.CondB),upper(WT.TitleF),upper(WT.PublisherA),upper(WT.SeriesA)) 
    FROM wt_table_one AS WT
    INNER JOIN public.ws_table_one AS WS ON WT.Index = WS.Index
    WHERE WS.View = 17
) t
WHERE  
    mycol LIKE '%PANTHER%'
    OR myval  LIKE '%WISHING%'
    OR (myval LIKE '%MIGHTY%' AND myval LIKE '%THOR%')
    OR (myval LIKE '%ANIMAL%' AND myval LIKE '%CROSSING%')
    OR (myval LIKE '%BRIAN%'  AND myval LIKE '%BLESSED%')
    OR (myval LIKE '%ONE%'    AND myval LIKE '%OF%' AND myval LIKE '%A%' AND myval  LIKE '%KIND%')
LIMIT 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT wt.*
FROM (SELECT wt.*,
             CONCAT_WS('', upper(WT.TitleA), upper(WT.CondB), upper(WT.TitleF), upper(WT.PublisherA), upper(WT.SeriesA)) as concat_str
      FROM wt_table_one wt JOIN
           public.ws_table_one ws
           ON WT.Index = WS.Index
      WHERE WS.View = 17
     ) wt
WHERE wt.concat_str LIKE '%PANTHER%' OR
      wt.concat_str LIKE '%WISHING%' OR
      (wt.concat_str LIKE '%MIGHTY%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%THOR%') OR
      (wt.concat_str LIKE '%ANIMAL%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%CROSSING%') OR
      (wt.concat_str LIKE '%BRIAN%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%BLESSED%') OR
      (wt.concat_str LIKE '%ONE%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%OF%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%A%' AND wt.concat_str LIKE '%KIND%')
      )
LIMIT 10000
```

You can also do this with a CTE or lateral join (if your database supports that).  You an probably also use regular expressions, if you database supports that.

Answer (score 0):

**Critique of existing code:**

- Don't you want `CONCAT_WS(' ',...`, not `CONCAT_WS('', ...)`, so that the words will be separated?
- Don't use `UPPER()` (or lower); use a collation that is "case insensitive.
- The use of `LIKE '%...'` and `OR` leads to scanning every string column in every row.  (Slow!)  (And the two current Answers, while satisfying the request for "concatvar", will go even slower.)

**For performance:"

When building the table add a `TEXT` column with all the words lumped together.  Then have a `FULLTEXT` index on that column.

Then use something like

```
MATCH(text_col) AGAINST (
     ''panther wishing "mighty thor" "animal crossing"'
     IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Read up on the features and limitations of `FULLTEXT`.  For example, `one of` may not be practical to include in the test.  (This is because of the min word length.)